# Packet jpeg optimization in linux

Tags: linux, find, sh

I have many JPEG images on my server and they added evry day. I need optimize this images.

To optimize it I have use next command

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -exec jpegoptim -m85 --strip-all {} \;
```

But find command finds all images, not only new! I know, that I may specify -ctime and -mtime params, but when jpegoptim optimizes image, image creation time changes to now! Therefore I can not specify last mod time for find command.

I think, that solution is save already processed files names in text file and when find command runs again exclude already processed file.

How can I do this? How to add finded file name in text file, and how check is file name in text file in next path?

Comment: If I starts this command at 5:00 every day with cron with -ctime -1 -mtime -1 then find finds all images changes during one day. Images was optimized yesterday will optimize again (they was optimized after 5:00 and has ctime less then 1 day ago!).

Comment: Ideally, either process them when they were uploaded, or at least keep a log of unprocessed files (then use that list to optimize, and then delete it).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `inotifywait` from the [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools) (or some other `inotify` frontend) to continuously monitor the folder which contains your jpegs and have them converted on the fly, as soon as they are uploaded.

```
$ inotifywait -mrq --format '%w%f' -e create . | while read file; do
      [ "${file##*.}" = "jpg" ] || continue;
      [ -f "${file}" ] || continue;
      echo "jpegoptim -m85 --strip-all '$file'";
  done
```

This watches for all file creations in the current folder (`-e create .`) recursively (`-r`) and you have to check for the file extension (`.jpg`) yourself as shown, which means that in case there will be lots of non-jpeg creations in the same folder this is an unnecessary overhead. If this is a problem for you, you could use the `--exclude` argument and specify a negated regex to filter out files that do not match the desired extension (which is cumbersome and does not look very nice and straight-forward) or you can checkout the current version from the git repo yourself which provides an `--include` filter (`v3.14` does not have it) and have `inotifywait` only report files already matching your criteria.

Also note that this will silently skip files with newlines in their filenames.